# How to find exact string match in a long string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to parse a Quake3 shader script file for a 3D engine of mine. I need to find the shader name inside a long string which is the accumulation of all script files. I use string::find() to find the first occurance (and only one if there is no duplication in the files). The problem is that sometimes it returns true, with the position of the first shader name substring instead of the exact shader name.

For example I have this shader name:

textures/castle_wall/castle_c46_a

The problem is that it returns true when it arrives at:

textures/castle_wall/castle_c46_a.tga

because the shader name is contained in it.

I need to ignore this case because it's a texture file name used in *another* shader of a different name. I know there might be a way to do this easily in another language (using regex?), but I haven't found a case for C++ on StackOverflow with the search engine.

So basically the code I use is:

```
if ((pos = m_scriptData->find(shaderName)) != m_scriptData->npos)
{
    // parse it

}
```

Where m_scriptData is the long string.

An example shader with the name of the shader at the beginning would be like this:

```
textures/skies/xtoxicsky_dm9
{
    qer_editorimage textures/skies/toxicsky.tga
    surfaceparm noimpact
    surfaceparm nolightmap
    q3map_globaltexture
    q3map_lightsubdivide 256
    q3map_surfacelight 400
    surfaceparm sky
    q3map_sun 1 1 0.5 150 30 60
    skyparms full 512 -
    {
        map textures/skies/inteldimclouds.tga
        tcMod scroll 0.1 0.1
        tcMod scale 3 2
    }
    {
        map textures/skies/intelredclouds.tga
        blendFunc add
        tcMod scroll 0.05 0.05
        tcMod scale 3 3
    }
}
```

I know I could extract the string entirely from the position it was found and check to see if there is a file extension there...but I was looking for a more elegant way to do this using string methods. Also, I have to check further on if the shader name might not be found below that one. And again, the same texture file might appear once more below. I have no problems parsing the shader itself though.

Comment: Isn't there an open source BNF grammar parser for this kind of files?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea.

Comment: Split the string into tokens, loop through the tokens, and test if it exactly matches the shader name.

Comment: string::find doesn’t return true or false.

Comment: Have a look at `std::regex`

Comment: Probably what Im going to do, except that I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have looked at the std::regex reference and was able to make it work.

This is the code I used:

```
bool XShaderParser::FindShader(const std::string& shaderName)
{
    std::regex reg(shaderName);
    std::smatch m;

    while(std::regex_search(*m_scriptData, m, reg))
    {
        for (auto x : m)
        {
            if (x.length() == shaderName.length())
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I had to compare if the string found was the same length as the shader name, which excludes texture file names because of the extra extension. Only problem, it's a bit slow.